# Названия столбцов из xtraGrid в xtraReport не переносится

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress, fastreport

данные из gridview отправляются так:

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
   report.printableComponentContainer1.PrintableComponent = gridControl;
ReportPrintTool preview = new ReportPrintTool(report);
preview.ShowRibbonPreview();
```

но при этом всём свойство ColumnHeaderAutoHeight у gridview установлено как true, и в программе текст в столбцах переносится, а вот в reporte не переносится. как исправить данную ситуацию?